Should a BOM file include the implementation dependencies or just the API?
As I understand (I may be wrong) in BOM file I should include only API dependencies. However, if BOM contains only API I have problems with IMPL dependencies versions.
To include BOM file I do
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.foo.bom</groupId>
     <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

And when I import my BOM file this way, I can't use BOM file properties in child pom (that imports BOM). For example, if in BOM file I have library.version property I can't access it in child pom.
So, if library has API and IMPL dependencies, should I add IMPL dependencies to BOM? If BOM properties were available in child pom I could declare in BOM only version and API dependencies but they are not.

I don't see any reason to not put impl dependencies into a BOM.
